# C# How to clear <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker>

Tags: development, people-picker

Please tell me how to clear the value "ClientPeoplePicker" in C#?

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" ID="PeoplePickerControlName" Required="true" ValidationEnabled="true" InitialHelpText="text" VisibleSuggestions="3" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="false" CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
PeoplePickerControlName.AllEntities.Clear();
```

Link about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.allentities.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Clear on the new form?

```
$('[id^=ClientPeoplePicker]').val('');
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: Not JS, in C#...

Comment: Sorry bout that.


picker.Accounts.Clear();
picker.Entities.Clear();
picker.ResolvedEntities.Clear();

Comment: Your code actually is peopleeditor, not clientpeoplepicker